# Way to tail Clojure Leiningen REPL when running headless?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, headless, tail

I'm running a headless Leiningen REPL for Clojure using the following command:

```
lein repl :headless :port 34567
```

Is there a way to tail the interactions with REPL?

Comment: Not sure if you mean seeing (redirecting) the contents of the standard error/output in another REPL connected from a different terminal? Probably this will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55710752/483566

Comment: `man script` maybe?